# How to show numeric keyboard immediately when entering in a textbox in iPad using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, keyboard, numeric

i'm developing a survey form for iPad using HTML5, CSS3 & Jquery. At requirement, in Postal Code show immediately numeric keyboard instead of characters keyboard then have to choose button to switch number keyboard. So in javascript, is it possible to do it ? if it is, how to do it ? please give some suggestion. Thanks all in advanced.

Comment: That's the HTML 5 `<input type='number'>`

Comment: i have tried it but when run survey in safari on iOS 5.0.1, the keyboard did not appear and can not focus or enter in the input with type='number' attribute

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it on my iPad to see which keyboard is displayed but if there is a way I'm sure it would be the [HTML 5 Input Type](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_form_input_types.asp).  This is what the new input type is supposed to do.  I would be mildly surprised if the iPad didn't behave as expected when you have the correct type set.

Try this code:
`<input type="number" name="mynumber"...>`

**Update:** It does work on my iPhone (iOS 5.0.1). It doesn't pull up the "numeric only" keyboard like you get when you are unlocking the phone, but it does pull up the "numbers and symbols" keyboard like you get when you click the "123" button on the normal keyboard.

**Update:** Type changed from 'numeric' to 'number'

Comment: In iOS if you want the 'phone' type keyboard, you should be able to set `type='phone'`

Comment: Oh yes, there is a way to pull up the phone keypad.  But according to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com) the spec is actually `type='tel'`.  Thanks for catching that Daniel!

Comment: I knew it was something like that!

Comment: I tried that but your solution did no work in iPad with iOS 5.0.1.

Comment: I just tried out the "Try It Yourself" links on my iPad (from the link I posted above) and they work as expected for both 'number' and 'tel'. The 'tel' keyword doesn't pull up the phone number keyboard on the iPad but it does pull up the numerical/symbol keyboard, same as the 'number' type. I'm running iOS 5.0.1 on both devices. Check the samples on the above link. Maybe there's something off in your markup? Are you putting the <input>s inside a <form> tag?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can add a attribute in your input as inputmode="numeric"
Example bellow:

```
$("input").attr("inputmode", "numeric");
```